# robot.txt allow instead of Disallow

Tags: html, seo, robots.txt

My app has few dynamic urls so is there any allow in robots.txt instead of Disallow? Like

```
User-agent: *
allow: / 
allow: /blog
```

or I have to do something like this?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /users/*
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There is and it's called "Allow".
You could even Disallow a full folder but a file this way:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /folder/
Allow: /folder/file.php
```